# Add a filtered table inside a pivot table in excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have an issue where I have to display data in an excel pivot table.

I have the pivot table working correctly but I need to add a filtered table nested inside the innermost level of the pivot table.

So it should look like this:

```
                  type1     type2     type3
Level 1             10        11        3
    Level 2         5         4         1
        Level 3     3         1         1
          Item Id: Color:  Spelling: Type:
            item 1  blue    one       type1
            item 2  green   two       type1
            item 3  brown   three     type2 
            item 4  yellow  four      type3
            item 5  white   five      type1
        ...
```

The pivot table adds up the values in the type column.
and underneath it needs to replicate the snippet of the data that is aggregated in the Level 3 row

The data source is a large table of data in another tab.

I want to know if it is possible to add this snippet table to the pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

A PivotTable is what it is. Why don't you just change the layout to Tabular, so that those headings appear across the top?